# How do you you use Named Credentials in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, namedcredentials

How do you use named credentials where a LWC makes the callout?

I have an apex controller where I'm getting the path and the user creds and passing it to LWC, and getting the error below in Chrome:

> aura_prod.js:88 Refused to connect to 'callout:myNamedCred/path'
> because it violates the document's Content Security Policy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the `callout:named_credential` syntax in Apex. If you want to use the Named Credential, you'll do so in Apex via an @AuraEnabled method.